# IOS app - downloading of resource files blocked by region?

Tags: ios, cordova, capacitor

got an issue I'm trying to get some details on in regards to an IOS app. We have a hybrid app where, on-load we download / save a .JS file to the device. This is so things can work properly offline etc.

Everything is working in both IOS and Android, however, for some reason when you are outside the US (north/south America) IOS appears to 'block' the download..

This seems very odd to me and I have been looking online to see if I can find any docs that mention behavior like this. I have tested this by opening the app via VPN and when I am set to the US everything works just fine, however if I switch to a region in the EU or anyone outside the Americas the save file wont work, it appears to block the action.

What is also odd is that the same app work on Android just fine, also the URL in question is whitelisted in the app.

Anyhow, just curious if anyone has ever seen this or knows why this may be happening, seems odd that only the 'Americas' could download a file??

Thanks for any insight here.